# Why does Laravel on localhost (xampp) run slow compared to a normal html site?

Tags: php, html, laravel, xampp

I use

XAMPP version: 8.2.4

Control Panel version: 3.3.0

Laravel: 10.33.0

PHP: 8.2.11

Everything should work as fast as lightning, but im waiting 32 seconds to load a page. *First image shows loading same page with Larevel and localhost*

[image]

As we can see from the image most of the time im speding waiting from server response. This page is clear html js css in blade.php there **is NO database query on this page**.
i tried to load same page without Laravel and localhost. *second image shows loading same page without localhost*

[image]

412 ms to load the same page in a different folder without Laravel and localhost.
Any solution to this problem?

to start server in laravel I use these commands

`php artisan serve`

and

`npm run dev`

***laravel debugbar***

[image]

Comment: why do you have 70 requests?

Comment: without Laravel i have 56 and works fine

Comment: yeah, are you not able to see which of those 70 request is slowing down?

Comment: the point is that without Laravel it goes much faster. The point is that something must be wrong on the Laravel side, because not only this page but every page loads much slower.

Comment: yeah, but you need to figure out first which of those 70 request is taking that so much time, you are just randomly guessing its laravel, but we can't even see on your screenshot the actual page return from laravel how long it takes, you can easily check all those request and see which one of them is taking so much time. otherwise all we can do is random guessing based on the info you've provided

Comment: also install laravel debugbar or clockwork, then include the data from either of them

Comment: @silver which debugbar tab send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a re-install of Xampp, Composer and a fresh install of Laravel and the results were stunning

[image]

and

[image]

*Laravel v10.39.0 (PHP v8.2.12) (XAMPP v8.2.12)*

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel debugbar it will give your more details/data u can identify the problem with

**Here u go :**

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: added I hope it will help in finding the problem

Comment: U can share now more details here

Comment: check my first post there is no more interesting data

Comment: So from the data shown in the debugbar , we now know that the problem the delay is occurring outside the realm of the Laravel application logic  , so u can try checking server configuration ,Consider changing maybe to Wamp just to see if the reason is on the Xampp level

Comment: currently I am installing new Laravel project on my second computer with new Xampp and Composer installation, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

It´s because XAMPP is slooooow.
Better use Laragon, it´s so much faster!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).